# Teamcity not excluding folder

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, clickonce

I am using Teamcity version 2017.2 (build 50574)

I am trying to create a zip archive artifact after successful build of my WPF app to be deployed using ClickOnce

However, teamcity is not excluding the folder and I still see it in the zip

Here are rules in my artifact paths section of teamcity:

```
//putting everything inside debug folder int zip
+:MySolution\MyProject.WPF\bin\Debug => MyProject%env.BUILD_NUMBER%.zip

//Iwant to ignore this folder, don't put it in zip
-:MySolution\MyProject.WPF\bin\Debug\app.publish => MyProject%env.BUILD_NUMBER%.zip

//Include config files from project directory in zip
+:MySolution\MyProject.WPF\App.*.config => MyProject%env.BUILD_NUMBER%.zip
```

I am not sure what I've done wrong. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. It was due to my own carelessness.
I was using a TeamCity parameter for build configuration and I wasn't passing it

-:MySolution\MyProject.WPF\bin\ **%DeployConfig%**\app.publish => MyProject%env.BUILD_NUMBER%.zip

Teamcity was using a blank value for **%DeployConfig%** so the path was wrong.